# Selection sort algorithm using pointer arithmetic

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I need to sort elements of array in ascending order using selection sort algorithm and pointer arithmetic.

That means the following (using pointer arithmetic):

- find the minimum element in unsorted array;
- swap the found minimum element with the first element
- repeat it until the end of array
- print sorted array

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(double **pp, double **qq) {
  double *temp = *pp;
  *pp = *qq;
  *qq = temp;
}
void sortArray(double arr[], int n) {
  double *q, *min;
  q = min = arr;
  while (min > arr + n) {
    while (q < arr + n) {
      if (*q < *min) 
        min = q;
        q++;
      }
      min++;
      swap(&min, &q);
  }
}
void writeSorted(double arr[], int n) {
  double *qq = arr;
  while (qq < arr + n) {
    printf("%g ", *qq);
    qq++;
  }
}
int main() {
  double arr[4] = {2.1, 4.23, 3.67, 1.5};
  int n = 4;
  sortArray(arr, n);
  writeSorted(arr, n);
  return 0;
}
```

This code prints the same unsorted array. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* your code? For example by using a *debugger* to step through it statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values?

Comment: As a hint: Swapping pointers to local variables is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: finding minimum value is correct, swaping and printing is wrong

Comment: `swap(&min, &q)` swaps `min` and `q` (which are both local variables), but it doesn't swap anything in `arr`. You need to swap the corresponding values inn the array.

Comment: No double indirection needed for swap – accept ordinary pointers to double and the double values directly (as the pointers point into the array, the array will get chagned).

Comment: Side note: Correct data type for specifying array sizes actually is `size_t`, not `int`. And I'd name the function simply `write`, as it could write out unsorted arrays as well...

Comment: `int n = 4;` is redundant and contains a magic number – prefer avoiding that, you can get sizes directly from the array (but needs *indeed* to be array, once decayed to pointer that doesn't work any more!): `sort(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr));`

Comment: General advice: The outermost (in your case sole) dimension of any array specification for function parameters is ignored anyway, but you can use that to write self-documenting code if you swap parameters: `void sort(size_t n, double arr[n]);`

Comment: @Aconcagua, even though declarations of function parameters as arrays are "*adjusted*" to pointer declarations, the compiler needs as a preliminary matter to accept the original array declaration.  An implementation that does not support VLAs probably will not accept your suggested revised function signature.  (But it's good advice if one does not care about supporting non-VLA implementations.)

Comment: @JohnBollinger Indeed, C++ wouldn't, for instance (if writing common header with "extern "C", etc)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error about the role of swap: you have to swap the elements, not the corresponding pointers.

Moreover, there is a confusion about definition and role of each pointer.
In particular, it is important to keep trace of the pointer to the start of next iteration.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(double *pp, double *qq) {
  double temp = *pp;
  *pp = *qq;
  *qq = temp;
}
void sortArray(double arr[], size_t n) {
  double *start = arr;
  while (start < arr + n) {
      double *q = start + 1;
      double *min = start;
      while (q < arr + n) {
          if (*q < *min) min = q;
          q++;
      }
    swap (start, min);
    start++;
  }
}
void writeArray(double arr[], size_t n) {
  double *qq = arr;
  while (qq < arr + n) {
    printf("%g ", *qq);
    qq++;
  }
  printf ("\n");
}
int main() {
  double arr[] = {2.1, 4.23, 3.67, 1.5};
  size_t n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
  writeArray (arr, n);
  sortArray(arr, n);
  writeArray(arr, n);
  return 0;
}
```

Besides, I don't know what are exactly your constraints for this exercise. Even by using pointers, some simplifications are possible. For example, for the print function:

```
void writeArray(double arr[], size_t n) {
  while (n--) {
    printf("%g ", *arr++);
  }
  printf ("\n");
}
```

Comment: @codproe You welcome.